# Array looping with unknown number of nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, nested

I have a json file that I am attempting to iterate through and write out to a new file.  The structure of the original array is basically an incident with incident updates nested below.

Here is a sample of the JSON file.  There can be numerous incident updates within the same incident.

```
    "incidents": [
        {
            "id": "86dzgm6jcrll",
            "name": "Issues generating a meeting event using the Google Suite",
            "status": "monitoring",
            "created_at": "2022-08-02T12:41:36.247-07:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-08-03T06:40:41.698-07:00",
            "monitoring_at": "2022-08-02T12:57:34.782-07:00",
            "resolved_at": null,
            "impact": "minor",
            "shortlink": "https://stspg.io/",
            "started_at": "2022-08-02T12:41:36.239-07:00",
            "page_id": "14qjgk812kgk",
            "incident_updates": [
                {
                    "id": "qf8qswrttdsy",
                    "status": "monitoring",
                    "body": "Incident update details",
                    "incident_id": "86dzgm6jcrll",
                    "created_at": "2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00",
                    "updated_at": "2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00",
                    "display_at": "2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00"
                 }
];
```

Here is my current function which does not error out, however it does not return the 7 "incident_updates" contained within the "incident".

```
    function processIncidents() {
        var source = JSON.parse(value);
        var incidents = source.incidents;
        var m, n, i, j;

        for (i = 0, m = incidents.length; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0, n = incidents[i].incident_updates.length; j < n; j++) {
                output = "{ \"data\" :["
                    output += "{\"id\": \"" + incidents[i].incident_updates[j].id + "\", \
                        \"incident_id\": \"" + incidents[i].incident_updates[j].incident_id + "\", \
                        \"status\": \"" + incidents[i].incident_updates[j].status + "\", \
                        \"body\": \"" + incidents[i].incident_updates[j].body.replace(/\s|:/g," ") + "\"},"
            }
                    output += "{\"id\": \"" + incidents[i].incident_updates[j].id + "\", \
                        \"incident_id\": \"" + incidents[i].incident_updates[j].incident_id + "\", \
                        \"status\": \"" + incidents[i].incident_updates[j].status + "\", \
                        \"body\": \"" + incidents[i].incident_updates[j].body.replace(/\s|:/g," ") + "\"}"
                output += "]}"
        }
    };
```

Comment: What is `len` (as in `incidents.len`) supposed to be here? `incidents.length`? Is there something you're using that makes `len` be a thing?

Comment: Tangentially related, you may be better off (a) using `map`, and/or (b) pulling out some temp vars to eliminate a lot of repetition, and/or (c) creating methods to shape the output data. It's not clear why the `output += "big honkin' string"` appears to be duplicated, or what's actually happening with `output` which is overwritten every inner loop iteration.

Comment: len is in fact length, I made a typo when I pasted my code (fixed it in this post).  As for the duplication, this is code that I located in another post and it has been working in other instances where there is only a single loop.  Javascript is very new to me, so I am sure this is far from clean and efficient code.

Comment: What worries me is not seeing `output` initialized externally to the two loops, and then I *do* see it initialized in the inner loop, that can't be right.

Comment: I'm... unclear how pasting would modify code, but ok :) This function doesn't return anything, and overwrites `output` on every iteration of the inner loop. It's not clear what output you want, or how that output should be created/"returned".

Comment: The output should come from the second loop.  First loop should find all incidents, the second should loop through the incident updates within the incident and output the results as defined in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I got your question right, but something like this should do the trick:

```
const processIncidents = (source) => {
  const updates = JSON.parse(source).incidents.map(incident => incident.incident_updates)
  const parsedUpdates = updates.flat().map(({ id, incident_id, status, body }) => ({
    id,
    incident_id,
    status,
    body: body.replace(/\s|:/g, ' ')
  }))

  return parsedUpdates
}
```

Edit: you can try it here

```js
const incidents = JSON.stringify({page: {}, components: {}, incidents: [
  {
    id: '86dzgm6jcrll',
    name: 'Issues generating a meeting event using the Google Suite',
    status: 'monitoring',
    created_at: '2022-08-02T12:41:36.247-07:00',
    updated_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.698-07:00',
    monitoring_at: '2022-08-02T12:57:34.782-07:00',
    resolved_at: null,
    impact: 'minor',
    shortlink: 'https://stspg.io/',
    started_at: '2022-08-02T12:41:36.239-07:00',
    page_id: '14qjgk812kgk',
    incident_updates: [
      {
        id: '1',
        status: 'monitoring',
        body: 'Incident update details',
        incident_id: '86dzgm6jcrll',
        created_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        updated_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        display_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00'
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        status: 'monitoring',
        body: 'Incident update details',
        incident_id: '86dzgm6jcrll',
        created_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        updated_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        display_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00'
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        status: 'monitoring',
        body: 'Incident update details',
        incident_id: '86dzgm6jcrll',
        created_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        updated_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        display_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00'
      },
      {
        id: '4',
        status: 'monitoring',
        body: 'Incident update details',
        incident_id: '86dzgm6jcrll',
        created_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        updated_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        display_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00'
      },
      {
        id: '5',
        status: 'monitoring',
        body: 'Incident update details',
        incident_id: '86dzgm6jcrll',
        created_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        updated_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        display_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00'
      },
      {
        id: '6',
        status: 'monitoring',
        body: 'Incident update details',
        incident_id: '86dzgm6jcrll',
        created_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        updated_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        display_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00'
      },
      {
        id: '7',
        status: 'monitoring',
        body: 'Incident update details',
        incident_id: '86dzgm6jcrll',
        created_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        updated_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00',
        display_at: '2022-08-03T06:40:41.695-07:00'
      }
    ]
  }
]})

const processIncidents = (source) => {
  const updates = JSON.parse(source).incidents.map(incident => incident.incident_updates)
  const parsedUpdates = updates.flat().map(({ id, incident_id, status, body }) => ({
    id,
    incident_id,
    status,
    body: body.replace(/\s|:/g, ' ')
  }))

  return parsedUpdates
}

console.log(processIncidents(incidents))
```

Comment: Thanks @warialer...I am trying this solution now.  The platform I am using seems to be throwing an error related to "duktape" which is the javascript package that it uses so i am trying to adapt?

Comment: I think I am getting closer thank you so much!  I am getting "Failed: SyntaxError: parse error".  In your example it works perfectly, but the structure of the JSON may be my issue.  Here is the true JSON path
 
x.incidents[0].incident_updates[0]
 
Do I need to alter the source path in your provided code.  The data I am dealing with currently has 1 "Incident" and 7 "Incident updates"?

Comment: yes @LennyConvis I tried to get the data format from what you posted, but I was not sure about the structure... You should try to adapt it to the actual json

Comment: @LennyConvis reading again your comment, maybe you can try using `x.incidents` instead of `x.incidents[0].incident_updates[0]` if i understood correctly.
the parser in my solution works already with an array of incidents, if you only pass the first incident_update cannot work

Comment: @LennyConvis i updated my answer and the code snippet according to your json, it should work now...

Comment: Thank you @wardialer!  So much appreciated!!  I have replaced the code and it now returns a parsing error on this line, const processIncidents = (source) => {

Comment: That is the first row on the function, I doubt the error is there... since it is a parsing error, the error should be the `JSON.parse` function... Maybe the "source" variable is wrongly formatted... I used exactly the same complete JSON you published before and it worked... i cannot add it here because it is way beyond the chars limit for an answer, but i guess the issue is in the data format. Maybe try experimenting removing the `parse` or the `stringify` part if they are not needed (it depends on how you get your data)